# celery any() statement giving wrong result inside task

Tags: python, celery

I have the following code that is running in a celery task, self.resdict['jobs'] contains a list of subtasks and I am checking the status of them in a while loop.

```
       while any([x.status for x in self.resdict['jobs'].values() if x.status is not 'SUCCESS']):
            print([x.status for x in self.resdict['jobs'].values() if x.status is not 'SUCCESS'])
            print(any([x.status for x in self.resdict['jobs'].values() if x.status is not 'SUCCESS']))
            time.sleep(.5)
       else:
            for a in self.resdict['accounts'][0]['result']:
                account = a['number'] if isinstance(a['number'], str) else False
                self.resdict[account] = self.resdict['jobs'][account].result[0]['result'][0]['Device Information']['subattributes']
```

When I run this code with CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True and CELERY_EAGER_PROPAGATES_EXCEPTIONS = True, it gives me the results I expect if the list contains all 'SUCCESS'

So what I am getting when I run with always eager:

```
print([x.status for x in self.resdict['jobs'].values() if x.status is not 'SUCCESS']) = ['SUCCESS', 'SUCCESS', 'SUCCESS', 'SUCCESS', 'SUCCESS', 'SUCCESS', 'SUCCESS', 'SUCCESS', 'SUCCESS', 'SUCCESS', 'SUCCESS', 'SUCCESS', 'SUCCESS', 'SUCCESS', 'SUCCESS', 'SUCCESS', 'SUCCESS']
print(any([x.status for x in self.resdict['jobs'].values() if x.status is not 'SUCCESS'])) = False
```

When I run without always eager, inside celery debug I see:

```
print([x.status for x in self.resdict['jobs'].values() if x.status is not 'SUCCESS']) = ['SUCCESS', 'SUCCESS', 'SUCCESS', 'SUCCESS', 'SUCCESS', 'SUCCESS', 'SUCCESS', 'SUCCESS', 'SUCCESS', 'SUCCESS', 'SUCCESS', 'SUCCESS', 'SUCCESS', 'SUCCESS', 'SUCCESS', 'SUCCESS', 'SUCCESS']
print(any([x.status for x in self.resdict['jobs'].values() if x.status is not 'SUCCESS'])) = True
```

Which is not correct since the list only contains 'SUCCESS'.

Any idea why celery is saying True when it should be False?

Answer (score 0):

You should not compare strings with `is`. It may sometimes work because some strings will be "interned" and cached by the Python interpreter, but this caching is not guaranteed to happen in all situations. Instead, you should compare by value instead of identity, using `==` instead of `is` and `!=` in place of `is not`.

That should fix your current issue, but I'd further suggest that you don't seem to be using `any` in a very useful way. The `any` function returns `True` after the first value in its iterable argument is truthy. If you just wanted to test for an empty list, skip `any` and just use the list itself as a Boolean value. Empty lists are falsey, while ones with any elements (regardless of those elements's values) are truthy.

Using `any` would make more sense if you don't build a list in the first place. That's because `any` short-circuits, stopping after the first truthy result without examining the rest of the iterable. This makes it a good match for a generator, which calculates its values lazily, only going as far as needed. You can replace a list comprehension with a generator expression, simply by removing the square brackets. But in this case I'd suggest changing your code so the generator yields `bool`s instead of either the value or nothing: `any(x.status != "Success" for x in self.resdict['jobs'].values())`